# Shapefile to pgadmin3

Tags: qgis

I have a shapefile of cadastral data which I want to link with a database, but unfortunately I can't...

[image]

I have tried almost every thing on these boxes and still I can't sort out the problem ... SPIT plugin is also not available in my QGIS version.

Comment: You would be better off showing this form with some of the values you have tried.

Comment: Have you looked at shp2pgsql?

Comment: thanks for your answer...... but believe me i've been there and done that ..... and the problem is still persisting

Comment: So, you want us to imagine what values you might have put in and what errors you might have had? I am sure it is frustrating, but how on earth can anyone help you when all you show is a blank form and no error message?

Comment: haha... sorry if it was offensive..... and yeah i'll sure work on that

Comment: Not offensive, just impossible to help based on provided info :D

Answer (score 1):

You can import data into PostGIS using the DB Manager in QGIS.

There is a guide that can be found in the QGIS manual:
http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/training_manual/databases/db_manager.html#importing-data-into-a-database-with-db-manager

Comment: shp2pgsql is another option, which is also a lot easier to script, debug, etc.

Comment: Or ogr2ogr... But the DB Manger is the easiest.

Comment: i cant find "Import layer/file button"

Comment: You evidentally have never had to load thousands of shp files at once. I assure you, the command line beats a GUI hands down in that situation. Actually, frankly, in any situation, as a GUI is always just a wrapper around the underlying function calls, so involves more clicking, is less easy to automate.

Comment: Hi @JohnBarça I have used ogr2ogr just for that (hundreds, not thousands). But I repeat DB manager is the easiest. I still use it if I'm loading a single ShapeFile. Feel free to add an answer using shp2pgsql.

Comment: ogr2ogr, sure, but that is command line too :-) You will never convince me to return to GUIs. I spend my day logged onto remote linux boxes -- the only time I ever use a GUI, QGIS, is to view the result of a complex query, usually a a shp file. Each to their own :D.